# post.save is not working (Node/Express/MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post, mongoose

I am new to node and creating api.
I am able to pass a json in request body and log it on console ,but problem is arising when I am trying to add this data to my database .
I am trying to add data to DB(cloud:Atlas) but post.save is not running .
This is my post.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true

    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true

    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', PostSchema)
```

This is controller (posts.js)

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Posts = require('../model/posts.model')

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('We are on posts page'))
router.get('/specific', (req, res) => res.send('We are on specific post page'))

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const post = new Posts({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    })

    // try{
    // const savedPost = await this.post.save()
    // res.json(savedPost)
    // }
    // catch(arr){
    //     res
    // }
    console.log('before save');

    post.save().then(data => {
        console.log("in then");

        res.json(data)
    })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('in catch');

            res.json({ message: err })
        })
})
module.exports = router
```

This is my app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bodyParser =require('body-parser')
require('dotenv/config')

//Import Routes
const postsRoutes = require('./routes/posts')

//Middelware
app.use(bodyParser.json())//to be used before app.use(<routes>)

app.use('/posts', postsRoutes)

//app.use(express.bodyParser())

//ROUTES
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('We are on home page'))

app.get('/posts', (req, res) => res.send('WE are on posts page '))

//Connect to DB

mongoose.connect('DB_CONNECTION', { useNewUrlParser: true }, () => console.log('Connected to db'))

//how to start listening to the server

app.listen(3000)
```

Console[image]

This is the req body:
[image]

Also when will collections form in my database?
Will it happen when I add first entry of data?

Comment: I am sure that in node you don't have to provide the extension .

Comment: No error in code the only mistake that I found is using ` bodyparser` `middleware` between your `routes`. So, put your `bodyParser` above` routes`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't connected to your monogodb. You have to add the ip address and the name of the database. 
In case there is not database with this name, it's going to create a new one.

```
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDB', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});
```